# ls recursive on home dir only with no flags specfied other than color

Tags: centos, ls, recursive, home

Like the topic says whenever I am in my home directory and run ls it shows me every file in every folder recursively, I cannot find any documentation of why this would happen, I have been looking on google everywhere to no avail. I'm not sure exactly when it started doing this so I'm not sure what the culprit is.

It also does this as root also, but it doesn't do this in any directory but the home directory.

This leads me to believe that it a setting on the directory or a file in it. Any help would be appreciated!

CentOS 6.4 64bit

```
dr-xr-xr-x 130 user     user      55M Dec 20 22:05 user

$ uname -a
Linux 3.10.9-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #1 SMP Wed Aug 21 11:51:59 CEST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ which ls
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
        /bin/ls
```

More info:

```
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'

$ type -a ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
ls is /bin/ls

$ ls
file1
file2
folder1
folder1\file3
folder1\file4
folder2
folder2\file5
folder3
file6
```

and so on and so forth it lists every file in the home directory and then each file in each folder

```
$ strace ls
write(1, "WWW_ERRORS\n", 11WWW_ERRORS
)            = 11
write(1, "WWW_ERRORS\\404.html\n", 20WWW_ERRORS\404.html
)  = 20
write(1, "WWW_ERRORS.rar\n", 15WWW_ERRORS.rar
)        = 15
write(1, "xbmc\n", 5xbmc
)                   = 5
close(1)                                = 0
munmap(0x3627ad0b000, 4096)             = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Comment: What does `type ls` say?

Comment: What happens when you call ls directly ? `/bin/ls`

Comment: Are you running `ls` or `ls *`? Does it happen if you run `/bin/sh`? If so, run `strace ls` and post the output (or at least as far as the block of `getdents` lines).

Comment: Added that info, just ls and yes if I do /bin/sh and then ls I get the same output. What I want it to do is what it used to, which is just show files and directories with color, as it is, it lists every file and directory and then the files in those directories. It only does this in the home directory, in no other folder does it do that. Even in folders within the home directory it does not do that, I'm lost as to what is wrong.

Comment: The \ instead of / is a mistake in reporting ls output, or is it really that?

Comment: I don't see any files in subdirectories here, and you posted the wrong part of the `strace` output. However, enzotib's comment is probably on the mark: did you by any chance believe that `folder1\file3` is a file in a subdirectory? It isn't, it's a file whose name happens to contain a backslash character. You aren't seeing a recursive directory listing (run `ls -R` to see what that looks like), you're seeing file names that contain a backslash. File names can contain any character other than a null byte or a slash (`/`, which is the directory separator).

Comment: Ok, I think you are right. I went into the WWW_ERRORS folder and there were no files in it. the 404 file should of been in there but it was actually in the same directory as the folder. It looks like I am still having problems with unrar doing that, I had a similar problem with unrar putting every file in the rar in the same folder, I guess I didn't make the connection that it did the same thing here in the home directory. I first noticed this problem when I upgraded from CentOS 5 32bit to CentOS 6 64bit I'm guessing for some reason that the rar files aren't compatible between the two. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure you're actually running the built-in `ls` and not some alias or function, run `command ls`. You can also check which options it's being run with by running `type ls`, as [@jordanm suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106095/ls-recursive-on-home-dir-only-with-no-flags-specfied-other-than-color#comment162787_106095). To see all the things `ls` can mean, run `type -a ls`.